# Find Stylesheet URLS

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to write a regular expression that finds stylesheets URLS within text.

I have looked at some pages and some style sheets have `.css` while some do not. Some have a `rel="stylesheet"` while some do not. Some have both and some have one or the other.

What can I do to find the stylesheets? Here is what I have so far:

```
preg_match_all("/<link.+href.+[\"'](.+\.css)[\"'].+>/isU", $this->html, $matches);
```

I am trying to do this without using the `Document Object Model`

Comment: "I am trying to do this without using the Document Object Model" — Are you inserting rusty screws under your toenails at the same time?

Comment: I am trying to write this for use on servers that don't have `DOM` installed

Comment: DOM is enabled by default. Why would anyone want to disable that? Switch hosting.

Comment: I really dont think that you should tolerate links without rel="stylesheed" since this is not only HTML5 standard.

Comment: its not enabled with PHP 4. Plus I am trying to write my own DOM (for grins and giggles). So, using the DOM to write a DOM is stupid

Comment: If your host is still running PHP4 you have much bigger problems.

Comment: It isn't my host, This is just a random project I am working on.